# How to use *.lib file in C# application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dll, .lib

So I have some .lib file (generated like [this one](http://wiki.videolan.org/GenerateLibFromDll)) How to use it from my C# WPF application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you want to use native libraries from C# you won't need a .lib file. The way this is handled in .NET is by using Platform Invoke (P/Invoke). I suggest you follow the tutorial on MSDN, it will get you started:

> **[Platform Invoke Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468.aspx)**

If you want to generate a wrapper you might want to have a look at the **[P/Invoke Interop Assistant](http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/)** on CodePlex. Please note that this tool works on the original C/C++ code. Using a .dll file to create a wrapper is not feasible because native DLLs don't store the signature of the exported functions (as described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386133/get-signatures-of-exported-functions-in-a-dll/386488#386488)) and a lib file will store the signature in a compiler specific way.

Comment: and can .lib file at least help me in creating a wraper?

Comment: If all you have is a .lib and .h file, you can create a dll wrapper for the lib, exporting the functions you need.

Comment: @Stephen Cleary: As this is about using native code from C# the lib file will not be needed. All you will need is the method signature and the name of the native dll that contains the method.