# Using a .lib file in a C# program

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, linker, static-libraries

I have a header file and a .lib file created using C++.

Now I want to use it in a C# program.  Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use \*.lib file in C# application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848193/how-to-use-lib-file-in-c-sharp-application)

Answer (score 1):

Not directly.  You can interoperate with unmanaged DLLs via P/Invoke, or mixed-mode assemblies using C++/CLI.  Either way, you'll have to create a wrapper project, or recompile the original .lib (if you have the sources) into DLL.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a .lib file.  But I do know if you compile your code as a DLL you can consume it as unmanaged code.

To do this you'll need to reference

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices
```

and you will need to define the method you want to use and give it the DllImport attribute.  Something like this:

```
[DllImport("MyCPPDll.dll")]
public void SomeMethod(int someParameter);
```

Here are a few links that should help point you in the right direction:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26thfadc(v=vs.100).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

There's not a traditional linker to let you import the lib.  Your best bet is to compile to a COM library and use interop to use it.

Answer (score 0):

C# compiler does not need nor use `.lib` files.

Important thing to note is that there are two flavors of `.lib` files:

1. **Static libraries**

   Those are meant to be statically linked to a C/C++ program. They are usually quite large. If this is what you have, and if you don't have a matching `.dll` file, then you are out of luck since static libraries cannot be directly used from a C# program.
2. **Import libraries**

   Those contain only function import data for C/C++ linker to consume while building the executable which uses the actual dynamically linked library (DLL). They are usually easy to spot because they are smaller in size and contain a bunch of `__imp__` prefixed function names at the start of file.

In any case, the header file has all the information needed to call the functions from a C/C++ library regardless of its type.

If the library you have is static, you will first have to create a C/C++ DLL project which wraps every function from this static library in order to be able to use it from a C# program. How to do that will largely depend on the library API design and the language it was written in (C or C++).

If you already have a DLL, then all you have to do is create a (usually static) C# class with all constants, structures, and functions listed in the header file [marshaled properly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/type-marshalling), and mark those library functions with `[DllImport]` to tell C# compiler which DLL they come from.

Finally, when creating a C# program which will use the library, you must also match the platform target -- set `x86` or `x64` explicitly instead of `Any CPU` depending on what your library platform target is.