# Extract method signature from arbitrary dll

Tags: .net, com, methods, interop

I'd like to create a testharness app for COM dlls.

In psuedocode:

- Examine target DLL and determine public object(s) methods
- Let the user pick an object, method and parameters
- instantiate the object and call the method with the appropriate params

I assume this is possible as it's effectively what VS does when it creates an Interop dll - but I have no idea how to examine an arbitrary dll and extract the relevant object/method/param information.

I'm assuming that the `Reflection` namespace won't help as it's not a .net dll - Where should I be looking?

Comment: Probably a duplicate question. Take a look here "Get signatures of exported functions in a DLL" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386133/get-signatures-of-exported-functions-in-a-dll

Comment: Study up on type libraries (TLB files).

Comment: Thanks both - and agreed, I'd call that a duplicate.