# Discover Method Signatures from an executable

Tags: c++, .net, reflection, reverse-engineering

I have what seems to be a VC++ executable and would like to be able to use some of its methods in my own code, so far I've managed to find [this article](http://sandsprite.com/CodeStuff/Using_an_exe_as_a_dll.html) explaining how to use the code. However, I do not know the signature of the method I'm looking for, so I searched a bit more and found [this SO posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386133/get-signatures-of-exported-functions-in-a-dll) that suggests the signatures are mangled.

So, is it possible to unmangle them? I mean, even if its by inspection, would it be possible? If so How do I extract the mangled method signatures?

Comment: In the future, please include [tag:C++] in the tags so people know you're not talking about C# or Java.

Answer (score 0):

Reflecting or decompiling isn't reverse engineering, but you could use a decompiler like [DotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) to look at what you are dealing with. If the code is obfuscated, the originator does not want anything like this to occur.

Comment: What I read is that the C++ mangles the signatures. I thought VC++ did not get MSIL code, and thusly you could not decompile it with the .net decompilers.