# Getting error when sending a char array to a DLL call "Don't know how to convert parameter"

Tags: python, dllimport

I am trying to recreate a DLL function call in Python. The code uses a DLL file to set the laser parameters for various material setting. Here is the original C# code:

```
public bool ApplyLasFile(string strLasFile)
{
    if (!File.Exists(strLasFile))
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("File not found", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        return false;
    }
    Char[] arr = strLasFile.ToCharArray();
    ApplyLAS(arr, strLasFile.Length);
    return true;
}
```

Here is my python code:

```
def setLaserSettings(input):
    #laserSettings(power (0-1000), speed (0-1000), height (0-4000), ppi (0-1000))
    input=input.upper()
    if(input=="ABS"):
        settings=laserSettings(825, 1000)
    elif(input=="STAINLESS"):
        settings=laserSettings(1000, 84)
    elif(input=="TITANIUM"):
        settings=laserSettings(1000, 84)
    else:
        return False
    charList=[]
    for x in range (0, len(settings)): #convert string into c_char[]
        charList.append(c_char(settings[x]))
    #print charList
    print ULSLib.ApplyLAS(charList, len(settings))
```

The DLL call `ULSLib.ApplyLAS(charList, len(settings))` is returning the error `ArgumentError: argument 1: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 1`. I started out with just using `list(settings)` to stand in for `ToCharArray()`, and when that didn't work I built a c_char array per the Python ctypes man page. However, I am still getting that error. Does anybody see what I am missing? Thanks for any help you can offer.

Edit: I have also tried `list(string)` and `list(charList)` and both return the same error.

Comment: What is the signature of the C function `ApplyLAS`?  If the first parameter is a `char *`, have you tried passing a `c_char_p` value?

Comment: Is this what you are talking about?

    `[DllImport("RemoteCtrl.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]`

    `internal static extern bool ApplyLAS(Char[] FileName, int nLength);`

This is what was at the top of the C# souce.

Comment: no, that's the signature of the C# method.  I was after the signature of the C function in the DLL.

Comment: Googleing `what is a dll signature` only brought up security related things. How would I go about finding the signature of the C function in the DLL? (Note: I was able to get this working, so this is purely for my own knowledge at this point.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386133/get-signatures-of-exported-functions-in-a-dll

Answer (score 0):

So this is weird. The function call requires a Char array, but putting the string strait into the function call within python seems to be getting the job done for some reason. I am new to python, so hopefully someday this will make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the reason that your code works unexpectedly is that the C function you are calling in the DLL takes a `char *` for its first parameter.  I'm guessing its declaration looks something like:

```
bool ApplyLAS(char *filename, int length);
```

I'm guessing the return type here, and it's also quite possible that the first parameter is actually a `wchar_t *` or the second is an `unsigned int`.  I'm also assuming your DLL has been compiled from C code.  It's possible it may have been compiled from another language such as Fortran instead.

A `char *` parameter, such as the one I suspect is in your C function, is typically how you pass a string to C.  Python's [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) module will pass a Python string to the C function as a `char *`, thereby making it easy to pass a string to C.